# analyze and memory alerts in xcode

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, ios4

I ran 'analyze" in xcode on a current iOS project to try to track down a freeze issue and there are a number of memory alerts that I don't understand (screenshot of one below).

What is going on there: I have a custom ObjC class extending NSObject; in the init method I alloc/init an NSMutableArray and then in a loop, populate it with NSMutableArrays. This nested array is declared as a property and released in dealloc(). It lives for the life of the app.

Am I doing this wrong? I don't understand the alert#3: @ object not referenced in this execution path and has a retain count of +1.

Since my class allocs the outer array, it owns it and will clean it up. Do the inner arrays need to be released?

Thanks for any tips - still new at this.

[image: screenshot of xcode memory alert]

**EDIT/ADDITION**
Trying to stamp out the additional memory warnings I am getting so I thought I would add to the question here in the event someone stumbles upon this w/ the same issue.

I am getting the following alert with the code below (the 2nd line "[keyArray addObject: etc").  What is going on: I have a custom class (Key - based on NSObject) that I instance and store in an array. Based on answers to my previous question, I guess my alloc increases the retain count and then when it is added to the array, the retain count isn't decremented - so the memory warning occurs.

What is the proper way to handle something like this? Use a placeholder like this:

```
Key * k = [[Key alloc] initKeyWithPath:path isBlackKey:NO]];
[keyArray addObject: k];
[k release];
```

Is that the proper way to do it? Or is there I way to write the custom class to return an autoreleased obj? (thanks and sorry to be so long winded!).

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line 460
>   Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
>   Object allocated on line 460 is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

```
-(void) addOctaveToArraysWithTransform:(CGAffineTransform*)trans andPath: (CGMutablePathRef) path
{
    path = [self createCF_keyUsingTransform: trans];
    [keyArray addObject:[[Key alloc] initKeyWithPath:path isBlackKey:NO]];
}
```

Key.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Key.h"

@interface Key : NSObject {
    @public
    CGMutablePathRef keyPath;
    BOOL isBlackKey;
    NSValue * path;
    int keyState;
    BOOL needsRedraw;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, assign) int keyState;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL needsRedraw;
 @property (nonatomic) CGMutablePathRef keyPath;

 -(id) initKeyWithPath:(CGMutablePathRef) aPath isBlackKey:(BOOL)flag;
 -(CGMutablePathRef) getKeyPath;

@end
```

Key.m

```
#import "Key.h"

@implementation Key

@synthesize keyState, needsRedraw, keyPath;

-(id) initKeyWithPath:(CGMutablePathRef) aPath isBlackKey:(BOOL)flag
{
    if ((self = [super init])){
         isBlackKey = flag;
         keyState = 0;
         needsRedraw = NO;
         keyPath = aPath;
         CGPathRetain(keyPath);
 }
return self;
}

-(CGMutablePathRef) getKeyPath
{
    return  keyPath;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an allocation of an NSMutableArray on each iteration of the for-loop.  Instead use: `NSMutableArray array]` which is a convenience method that return an autoreleased NSMUtableArray suitable for adding to `fieldNotes` which will retain the `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to release the inner arrays to balance the alloc/init. Remember the outer array will retain each inner array, and the outer array will presumably release those later. But here you are still responsible for the alloc/init you just did.

Hope that helps.